# Однородные сказуемые разного вида

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые, однородные-члены

**Доход ежемесячный и оформляется юридически.**

**Такая реклама не содержит призывов к покупке, максимально адаптируется под потребности пользователя и поэтому не вызывает отторжения.**

**Ты всегда на расслабоне, внушаешь спокойствие и оказываешь стабилизирующее воздействие, когда все вокруг начинают терять голову.**

**Настоящие эксперты всегда спокойны, в хорошем настроении и даже немного на расслабоне.**

Допустимо ли составлять предложение так, чтобы однородные сказуемые были в разном залоге или разного типа — простое и составное именное? Или с  именными частями разного вида?

Нашёл только такое правило:

"Однородные члены могут быть выражены одинаковыми и разнотипными морфологическими формами. ...Однако предпочтительным в речевой практике является употребление однородных членов с однотипными морфологическими формами. В ряде случаев использование одинакового морфологического выражения считается обязательным с точки зрения норм литературного языка" ([Предложения с однородными членами. Ошибки, связанные с использованием однородных членов. | Издательство «ЛИЦЕЙ»](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/784-34_predlozheniya_s_odnorodnymi_chlenami.html)).

Comment: Знаете, всё, что не запрещено, все разрешено. Если не нашли правила, явно запрещающего такую конструкцию, то считайте, что она разрешена грамматически. Другое дело, что такое построение предложения вызывает ощущение небрежности или, наоборот, слишком высокого стиля, не подходящего данному контексту.

Comment: Что-то близкое можете найти в понятии "силлепс". Ну хотя бы  здесь.https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%81  Это не совсем точное соответвие, но аналогия близкая.

Answer (score 2):

### Ответ Граммы.ру

**Специфика делового (официально-делового)** стиля речи в том и заключается,
чтобы максимально точно передать смысл высказывания и исключить
возможность разночтений. Пример того, как может выглядеть предложение,
если соблюсти требования к его речевому оформлению: **"Доход ежемесячный и
оформляемый юридически"** (характеристика типа/вида дохода).